# Best way to add custom user actions logic log inside application

Tags: .net, sql-server, logging

Im about to start an application where I have to add "Custom User Actions Logic Log".

For example, if the user access the "Employee Module", and go to "Personal Information" and he changes the first name, then I should log that the user changed personal information on dd/mm/yyyy at hh:mm:ss

If the user add a new dependent to the employee then I should log that the user added a new dependant action, and so on.

So basically its not going to be an audit trail of what fields were modified, original value, etc... its a **basic actions log**. And the actions are going to be customized. So not all the actions are going to be logged.

Does any one know what database structure would be enough flexible to do that for an entire applications and modules and what log framework to use: log4net or Microsoft's Enterprise Library?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546601/best-way-to-implement-an-audit-trail-in-sql-server

Comment: Or this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962398/creating-audit-triggers-in-sql-server