# Trigger to log inserted/updated/deleted values SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I'm using SQL Server 2012 Express and since I'm really used to PL/SQL it's a little hard to find some answers to my T-SQL questions.

**What I have:** about 7 tables with distinct columns and an additional one for logging inserted/updated/deleted values from the other 7.

**Question:** how can I create one trigger per table so that it stores the modified data on the `Log` table, considering I can't used Change Data Capture because I'm using the SQL Server Express edition?

**Additional info:** there is only two columns in the `Logs` table that I need help filling; the altered data from all the columns merged, example below:

```
CREATE TABLE USER_DATA
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    NAME NVARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
    PROFILE INT NOT NULL,
    DATE_ADDED DATETIME2 NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE AUDIT_LOG
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    USER_ALTZ NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    MACHINE SYSNAME NOT NULL,
    DATE_ALTERERED DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
    DATA_INSERTED  XML,
    DATA_DELETED XML
)
GO
```

The columns I need help filling are the last two (`DATA_INSERTED` and `DATA_DELETED`). I'm not even sure if the data type should be XML, but when someone either

`INSERTS` or `UPDATES` (new values only), all data inserted/updated on the *all columns* of `USER_DATA` should be merged somehow on the `DATA_INSERTED`.

`DELETES` or `UPDATES` (old values only), all data deleted/updated on the *all columns* of `USER_DATA` should be merged somehow on the `DATA_DELETED`.

Is it possible?

Comment: I would prefer to have an audit for each table instead of one generic one. It makes looking at the history a LOT simpler. If you store everything as XML you have to shred all that XML to look at the history.

Comment: @SeanLange Hey, Thanks! I did not known about "audit". I google-searched about it and found the solution that I wanted (kind of, will have to modify a procedure for my needs) on the first link from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17546860/2970272). Please post it as an answer so I can accept it. Cheers!

Comment: The post you linked described pretty much what I was talking about. I don't care about the points and I don't want to rewrite that just to get some points. Glad you found a workable solution.

Comment: Glad you wrote a comment making be aware of what an "audit" was!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posting because this is what solved my problem. As user @SeanLange said in the comments to my post, he said to me to use an `"audit"`, which I didn't know it existed.

Googling it, led me to [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17546860/2970272) where the first link there is a procedure that creates triggers and "shadow" tables doing sort of what I needed (it didn't merge all values into one column, but it fits the job).

Answer (score 0):

[Use the inserted and deleted Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> DML trigger statements use two special tables: the deleted table and
>   the inserted tables. SQL Server automatically creates and manages
>   these tables. You can use these temporary, memory-resident tables to
>   test the effects of certain data modifications and to set conditions
>   for DML trigger actions. You cannot directly modify the data in the
>   tables or perform data definition language (DDL) operations on the
>   tables, such as CREATE INDEX. In DML triggers, the inserted and
>   deleted tables are primarily used to perform the following: Extend
>   referential integrity between tables. Insert or update data in base
>   tables underlying a view. Test for errors and take action based on the
>   error. Find the difference between the state of a table before and
>   after a data modification and take actions based on that difference.

And

[OUTPUT Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

> Returns information from, or expressions based on, each row affected
>   by an INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement. These results can be
>   returned to the processing application for use in such things as
>   confirmation messages, archiving, and other such application
>   requirements. The results can also be inserted into a table or table
>   variable. Additionally, you can capture the results of an OUTPUT
>   clause in a nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement, and
>   insert those results into a target table or view.