# After Update Trigger Insert old records to another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have MedicalAllowance Table i want to make vesrion from this table as history table "MedicalAllowanceHistory" i want to create trigger to do that after update 
MedicalAllowance Table copy data to "MedicalAllowanceHistory" table .which way is better to do that .

MedicalAllowance  table

```
ID | Employee_ID | Limit | Used | Balance
```

MedicalAllowanceHistory table

```
ID | Employee_ID | Limit | Used | Balance
```

Comment: please explaine what is your point to do that? Do you wanna do that to log "MedicalAllowanceHistory" or any usage else?

Comment: I would tell you to implement using bests pratices to audit and trail tables but I don't know your requirements nor your SQL Server version. However you should look this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546601/best-way-to-implement-an-audit-trail-in-sql-server

Comment: I would suggest having more details than just the old values. Otherwise you won't ever be able to work out the change of values over time.

Comment: At a minimum it probably makes sense to also log the date/time of the change and the user, to the extent it can be determined, responsible. Having a bag of history rows with no order isn't very useful for most applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a trigger for that
But I would also store the date of the event, and the kind of event (insert, update or delete)
Here is an example to get you started

```
CREATE trigger tr_UID_MedicalAllowance on dbo.MedicalAllowance
after update, insert, delete
as
begin
    set nocount on

    declare @Insert bit = 0
    declare @Update bit = 0
    declare @Delete bit = 0

    --find out why we where triggered
    if (exists(select 1 from inserted)) and (exists(select 1 from deleted))
        set @Update = 1
    else if (exists(select 1 from inserted))
        set @Insert = 1
    else if (exists (select 1 from deleted))
        set @Delete = 1

    if @Update = 1
    begin
         insert into MedicalAllowanceHistory (
                     MedicalAllowanceID, 
                     HistoryDate, 
                     HistoryEvent, 
                     other columns...)
         select i.MedicalAllowanceID,
                getdate(),
                'UPDATED',
                i.other columns...
         from   inserted i
    end

    if @Insert = 1
    begin
         insert into MedicalAllowanceHistory (
                     MedicalAllowanceID, 
                     HistoryDate, 
                     HistoryEvent, 
                     other columns...)
         select i.MedicalAllowanceID,
                getdate(),
                'INSERTED',
                i.other columns...
         from   inserted i
    end

    if @Delete = 1
    begin
         insert into MedicalAllowanceHistory (
                     MedicalAllowanceID, 
                     HistoryDate, 
                     HistoryEvent, 
                     other columns...)
         select d.MedicalAllowanceID,
                getdate(),
                'DELETED',
                d.other columns...
         from   deleted d
    end
end
```

It is also possible to store old and new values in case of update, the new values are in the `inserted` table and the old are in the `deleted` table.
In that case the `update` part could look something like this

```
if @Update = 1
begin
     insert into MedicalAllowanceHistory (
                 MedicalAllowanceID, 
                 HistoryDate, 
                 HistoryEvent, 

                 NewLimit,
                 OldLimit,

                 other columns...)
     select i.MedicalAllowanceID,
            getdate(),
            'UPDATED',

            i.Limit,
            d.Limit,

            other columns...
     from   inserted i
       inner join deleted d on i.MedicalAllowanceID = d.MedicalAllowanceID
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following example to solve your problem:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_MedicalAllowance ON MedicalAllowance
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT MedicalAllowanceHistory
  SELECT ID,Employee_ID,Limit,Used,balance
  FROM deleted
END
```

Comment: How will that work on Updates? That's an `INSERT` trigger.

Comment: That doesn't fix the issue. `inserted` is the **new** data, so you just have 2 copies of the latest version (this the initial version would be lost). It also doesn't help for traceability just copying the columns and not adding additional metadata.

Comment: I changed `inserted` to `deleted`, and added `AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE`, as I believe this was the intent Kesava was going for.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use "Change Data Capture" instead of "Trigger". In this solution SQL tracks any changes. If you have need to learn more about it,click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).