# How to track data changes in a SQL Server database table

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a data change happen time to time in a specific table in my database.
I have already checked all the scheduled jobs and triggers, but I couldn't find anything - how can I track such changes?

Comment: Voted to close.  Question should be asked on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can try searching for Auditing Techniques for SQL Server, some of which are suggested in - https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/sql-server-database-auditing-techniques/

Comment: Also answered - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546601/best-way-to-implement-an-audit-trail-in-sql-server