# How Does One Fill a Typed DataSet, Keep it Synchronized, and Receive Updates When the Data Changes?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, synchronization, dataset

So I'm developing an application that works as sort of a "sidekick" to a large proprietary application which I do not have the source code for nor the rights to modify. The proprietary application *does* store all of its data in a Microsoft SQL database (version 2008 R2 or higher, I believe), however, and I have a good idea what the data represents. What I need my application to do is to constantly monitor the data as it is being added, updated, and deleted, and then act on the data automatically (such as raising alerts).

The issue is figuring out the best approach to receiving changes made to the database by the other application as they're happening, because I *don't wanna miss a beat*.

Here is *what I have done so far*:

1. **LINQ to SQL**: As far as I know, each time I run a query, I receive a new set of data, but I do not get the ability to receive the changes only or be notified of changes.
2. **Typed DataSet using DataSet.Load**:

   ```
   using (IDataReader reader = dataSetInstance.CreateDataReader())
   {
       dataSetInstance.Load(reader, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, dataSetInstance.Table1, dataSetInstance.Table2, dataSetInstance.Table3);
   }
   ```

   This didn't work out too well when I did it. `dataSetInstance` only contained a set of unfilled tables after calling the `Load` method. I was hoping to call `dataSetInstance.GetChanges` and `dataSetInstance.AcceptChanges` at regular intervals after the first call to `dataSetInstance.Load` to get only the changes. Am I doing it wrong?
3. **Typed DataSet with tables filled individually using their associated table adapters**:

   ```
   using (Table1TableAdapter adapter = new Table1TableAdapter())
   {
       adapter.Fill(dataSetInstance.Table1);
   }

   using (Table2TableAdapter adapter = new Table2TableAdapter())
   {
       adapter.Fill(dataSetInstance.Table2);
   }

   using (Table3TableAdapter adapter = new Table3TableAdapter())
   {
       adapter.Fill(dataSetInstance.Table3);
   }
   ```

   Of course, the problem is that there are actually way more than 3 tables which can add up to quite a lot of repetitive code (and maintenance work), but the real problem is that I will not receive any change notifications since I'm not using the `Load`/`AcceptChanges` methods (according to the documentation).
4. **Row retrieval by date/time field**: This was something I started work on, but something I stopped after observing the other application modify fields in the rows after creating them. Consider this:
       There is a row with a time stamp of a transaction and a boolean field that specifies if the transaction was canceled later on. If it is canceled, the other application simply goes back to that row and toggles the value. The time stamp remains the same, and my application will never know of the news. There is no *statute of limitations*; the other application can change this field any time in the future.

By the way, I should mention that this other application does not implement any constraints within the database such as foreign and primary keys. I believe I read somewhere in the documentation that for row update events and such to fire on the typed DataTable classes, some sort of primary key is needed.

There must be some way to do this!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered [SQL Server Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)? This uses SQL Server Service Broker under the covers.

[SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) is the C# class to look at.

- [Using SqlDependency in a Windows Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a52dhwx7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)   (.NET Framework 2.0 example: should be very similar to later versions.)
- [SqlDependency in an ASP.NET Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dz445ks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Phew! That was a lot to digest. I Googled/Binged everything I could think of pertaining to the problem. It seems that SQL Server Notifications only tell what kind of changes were made and for what query, but nothing about the specific rows/columns/cells that were changed. I suppose it's better than rereading the entire table (which can take 10 seconds on the system and also bring all other processes to a crawl). So far, it's the best solution offered for SQL Server and I'm going to have to use it carefully, monitoring queries that are likely to change, while tolerating a bit of stale data.

Answer (score 0):

I’d consider solving this at SQL Server level by implementing auditing triggers or SQL Server traces.

Triggers – idea is to add triggers to all tables you want to monitor. Triggers will catch all changes and store the data in some other “history” table. Once this is setup all your application needs to do is to read from these tables.

Check this for more details [Creating audit triggers in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962398/creating-audit-triggers-in-sql-server)

Traces – you can setup SQL Server traces that will store all info in trace files and then your app can parse trace files and see what’s going on.

Comment: I cannot make changes to the database. The other application is _proprietary_, and I do not have another copy for testing so any code I deploy will not have been tested for negative interactions with the other application. If the other application throws a fit and goes down because of the database modifications, that's money lost to downtime…

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be no silver bullet to the problem given the conditions, but anything is better than polling the database for changes every minute. What I will probably do now is take [Mitch Wheat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16076/)'s suggestion and work from there:

- Some tables have rows that are highly likely to change. A recent purchase, for example, is more likely to be cancelled than one from 7 days ago, or 6 months ago, or in the case of 1 year—probably never. The application will only need to monitor queries restricted to a certain time range. Older (in terms of creation time) rows will simply be refreshed at a much slower rate and without prompting from SQL Server query notifications. The application is going to have to tolerate some stale data in order to not needlessly pull entire tables from the database every minute.
- For tables without chronological information, the application will have to receive notifications for queries on conditions that are important or have to be acted on right away such as `WHERE Quantity < 0`.
- Some more clever approaches will need to be taken for the rest of the tables. Some tables are never updated nor their rows deleted, but they will gain new rows whenever some other table's rows changes. For example: every time the `NumberOfPeople` value changes for a row in table `Room`, another row is added to one of the tables `CheckIn` or `CheckOut`.

A lot more code needs to be written, but the application is probably going to be doing a lot less unnecessary work when it's running.