# SQL function to search across all columns in view for a string

Tags: sql, t-sql, function, view

I have a table with 99 columns and a rowid:

```
[RowID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Col1] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Col2] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Col3] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Col4] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
.......
[Col99] [nvarchar](max) NULL
```

[image: Table]

I need a function that can be used in a Micrsoft SQL Server view (must be a view and no variables in the view) to search for a unique string and then display as a new field in the view. My current approach is using a case statement to search through each column until the unique string is found. This approach is cumbersome to write out (inefficient) and I have several unique strings to search for.

```
    SELECT     RowID, COALESCE (
    CASE WHEN Col1 LIKE '%UniqueString%' THEN Col1 ELSE NULL END, 
    CASE WHEN Col2 LIKE '%UniqueString%' THEN Col2 ELSE NULL END, 
    CASE WHEN Col3 LIKE '%UniqueString%' THEN Col3 ELSE NULL END, 
    CASE WHEN Col4 LIKE '%UniqueString%' THEN Col4 ELSE NULL END, 
    CASE WHEN Col5 LIKE '%UniqueString%' THEN Col5 ELSE NULL END, 
    CASE WHEN Col6 LIKE '%UniqueString%' THEN Col6 ELSE NULL END,  
    ………..
    CASE WHEN Col99 LIKE '%UniqueString%' THEN Col99 ELSE NULL END) AS [UniequeString] 
    FROM         dbo.TABLE_A
```

The end view should have the following result:

[image]

Comment: so the string could be only in one or zero column for each row?

Comment: You have several unique strings to search for?  Then what you do display in the output column UniqueString

Answer (score 2):

In you example `'UNIQUESTRING'` is the value of the column.  If this is the case, then using `like` is overkill.  You can do:

```
select (case when 'UNIQUESTRING' in (col1, col2, . . ., col99) then 'UNIQUESTRING'
        end)
```

Another possibility.  It looks like the `UNIQUESTRING` is in the first non-NULL value for each column.  If so, you can do:

```
select (case when coalesce(col1, col2, . . . col99) like '%UNIQUESTRING%'
             then coalesce(col1, col2, . . . col99)
        end)
```

Comment: @user1783736 . . . These formulations do not make that assumption.  Each returns the first column that might have the value.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than 10 columns, you don't want to specify it explicitly. Instead, use [Columns to Rows XML trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18026432/1744834):

```
;with cte1 as (
  select t.RowID, (select t.* for xml raw('row'), type) as Data
  from Temp1 as t
), cte2 as (
    select
         C.RowID,
         F.C.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(128)') as Name,
         F.C.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as Value
    from cte1 as c
        outer apply c.Data.nodes('row/@*') as F(C)
)
select
    RowID,
    max(
        case
            when Name = 'RowID' then null
            when Value like '%uniquestring%' then Value
        end
    ) as Value
from cte2
group by RowID
```

[**sql fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0b43b/5) example