# Transposing sql table in java

Tags: java, sql

I have a following student table in SQL:

```
ID      |   Name   |   Jan   | Feb    |   Mar   |    Apr
---------------------------------------------------------
1       |   Ram    |   Paid  |  Paid  |  Unpaid  |  Unpaid
2       |   Hari   |   Paid  |  Unpaid|  Unpaid  |  Unpaid
```

I have a table that has id and name in my JTable

```
ID    |   Name
---------------
1     |   Ram
2     |   Hari
```

When I click on the first row I want to get another table showing payments:

```
Month |  Status
----------------
Jan   |  Paid
Feb   |  Paid
Mar   |  Unpaid
Apr   |  Unpaid
```

These payments details should come from same SQL table (the first) one....
How do I get the Payment table transposing the part of SQL table?

Comment: you may need to look into pivot tables

Comment: try this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026236/sql-server-columns-to-rows