# Pivot 1 row and n columns to n rows and 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a table with a number of columns that is unknown to me, but only a single row:

```
A B C D E F G...n
1 2 3 4 5 6 7...x
```

And I would like to pivot it into a table of `LABEL:VALUE pairs:`

```
LABEL    VALUE 
 A         1  
 B         2  
 C         3  
...       ... 
 n         x
```

This seems like it should be a regular pivot (I think...sorry, a bit of a n00b to SQL), but don't I need to know the names of the columns that I wish to pivot, preventing me from pivoting an unknown number of columns? Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you know the possible _names_ of the columns even if you don't know how many there will be?

Comment: D Stanley:  I could swing the names, but not the quantity. <br> <br>

xQbert:  That does look close! Thank you, I didn't see that one when I was searching to post this question. I'll check it out!

Comment: @xQbert That wouldn't be a correct duplicate, this is an unpivot not a pivot.

Comment: @KennethTomplait You need to look for unpivot solutions, which convert multiple columns into rows.  This is not a pivot.  See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026236/sql-server-columns-to-rows

Comment: Thanks, guys, and sorry for the duplicate. A friend showed me how I was screwing up, and here is the solution in case anyone stumbles on this one:

DECLARE TEST TABLE
(
 THING1 VARCHAR (MAX),
 THING2 VARCHAR (MAX),
 THING3 VARCHAR (MAX),
 THING4 VARCHAR (MAX)
)

INSERT INTO TEST
SELECT 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'


SELECT * FROM TEST

SELECT NAME, VALUE FROM 

(
SELECT [THING1], [THING2], [THING3], [THING4] FROM TEST

) AS UP
UNPIVOT
(
 --NAME
 --FOR details in ([THING1], [THING2], [THING3], [THING4])
 
 VALUE
 FOR NAME IN ([THING1], [THING2], [THING3], [THING4])
) u;

(Ampersands removed)