# Convert columns to rows by ID

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Looking for a way to convert columns to rows in sql server.

I have a table with the columns below:

```
[ID] [Action] [Note] [Resolution]
```

Here is what I want to get as the result with the columns: `[ID] [Notes]` 
And the result values will be:

```
'1' 'Action1'
'1' 'Note1'
'1' 'Resolution1'
'2' 'Action2'
'2' 'Note2'
'2' 'Note2.1'
'2' 'Resolution2' etc
```

Any ideas how I could do this in T-SQL? Also for the note field there could be multiple entries. Thanks!

Comment: What you want is know as `unpivot`. There are several questions here explaining it, as well as the manual.

Comment: Especially the "multiple Note entries" are not clear to me: please provide realistic sample data and expected output

Comment: Thanks for your replies. For the notes, in the source table an [id] could be in the table with the same action and resolution but different data for the notes. So multiple rows with the same ID, action  and resolution. So I am looking to convert them to rows grouped by id with Actions, then any notes  and then the resolution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server : Columns to Rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026236/sql-server-columns-to-rows)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your source table and data looks like this:

```
-- select * from t:
ID  Action  Note    Resolution
--- ------- ------- -----------
1   Action1 Note1   Resolution1
2   Action2 Note2   Resolution2
2   Action2 Note2.1 Resolution2
```

This query:

```
select distinct id, notes
from (select * from t) as source
unpivot (notes for ids in ([action], [note], [resolution])
) as unpivotted_table
```

will produce this result:

```
id  notes
--- ------
1   Action1
1   Note1
1   Resolution1
2   Action2
2   Note2
2   Note2.1
2   Resolution2
```

which looks a lot like what you are asking for.

You can find more information on how the `unpivot` operator works [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).