# Unpivot all values into a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a really wide table.  All I want to do is put each value for the row into a single column.  I also cannot hard code the column names as ill perform this operation on a number of different tables. So, it has to be dynamic.  Lastly, please assume that there is only ever one row in the table.

Is there a simple way to UNPIVOT every value in a table?

**Current**

```
Col_A   Col_B   Col_C   Col_D
  a        b      c       d
```

**Desired Result**

```
Col_Index   Col_Value
    1           a
    2           b
    3           c
    4           d
```

Traditional examples of unpivot are not helpful as i need a simple, and dynamic, way of unpivoting every row/column.  Unpivot is applicable to one or several, not all.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026236/sql-server-columns-to-rows

Comment: Please refer [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: neither of these are helpful.  I'm not trying to unpivot one value. I'm trying to unpivot every value.

Comment: when you unpivot, you have to convert all values to the same type.. is this something that will even be useful for you?

Comment: i think i just hit that issue.  Yeah, its fine, i can just make everything a string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server : Columns to Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026236/sql-server-columns-to-rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get the ordinal position as Col_Index and the converted fields as Col_Value dynamically

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @columns NVARCHAR(Max),
        @ordinals NVARCHAR(Max),
        @table VARCHAR(200) = 'table'



SELECT @columns = STUFF ((SELECT    ',CAST(' + QUOTENAME(column_name) + ' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS ' + QUOTENAME(ORDINAL_POSITION)
                          FROM      information_schema.columns 
                          WHERE     table_name=@table
                          ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''),
        @ordinals = STUFF ((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(ORDINAL_POSITION)
                          FROM      information_schema.columns 
                          WHERE     table_name=@table
                          ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')

SET @sql = N'
    SELECT  Col_Index,
            Col_Value
    FROM    ( SELECT ' +  @columns + ' FROM ' + @table + ') t
    UNPIVOT (
        Col_Value
        FOR Col_Index in (' + @ordinals + ')
    ) up
'
```

if you have multiple schemas, you will need to define that along with the table name, and prepend that to the table name in your select query

Comment: you are an SQL God and I worship you

Answer (score 0):

```
select a1.*,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) as col_index from #t t
cross apply
(
values(col_a),
      (col_b),
      (col_c),
      (col_d)
)a1(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE Table
ColTable
(
    Col_A VARCHAR(256),
    Col_B VARCHAR(256),
    Col_C VARCHAR(256),
    Col_D VARCHAR(256),
)

INSERT INTO ColTable (Col_A,Col_B,Col_C,Col_D)
Values ('a','b','c','d')

SELECT * FROM ColTable


SELECT
    Ordinal AS Col_Index
    ,ColInfo AS Col_Value
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        Col_A
        ,Col_B
        ,Col_C
        ,Col_D
        ,1 AS [OrdinalA]
        ,2 AS [OrdinalB]
        ,3 AS [OrdinalC]
        ,4 AS [OrdinalD]
    FROM 
        ColTable
    ) AS d
    UNPIVOT
    (
        ColInfo FOR ColInfos IN (Col_A, Col_B, Col_C, Col_D)
    ) AS l
    UNPIVOT
    (
        Ordinal FOR Ordinals IN (OrdinalA, OrdinalB, OrdinalC, OrdinalD)
    ) AS o
WHERE
    RIGHT(ColInfos,1) = RIGHT(Ordinals,1)


DROP TABLE ColTable
```