# transform table in t-sql columns to rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in sql with the following data:

```
[col1]  [col2]
1       aabb
2       ccdd
3       eeff
4       gghh
1       uuii
2       oopp
3       hhjj
4       lltt
...
```

The values in col1 are always known. How can I transform this in a table where the values of the first column will be the new columns like this:

```
[1]   [2]   [3]   [4]
aabb  ccdd  eeff  gghh
uuii  oopp  hhjj  lltt
...
```

Comment: Is it always 4 columns ? and Did you try anything ?

Comment: I tryed using pivot but pivot requires the use of an agregator function and I don't want to aggregate any data

Comment: @Prdp It's always a fixed number of columns but not always 4

Comment: What a contradicting statement that was

Comment: I'll try to clarify. For any given table the number of columns is fixed.

Comment: am taking about result. In result will it be always 4 columns ?

Comment: You can still pivot, forcing an aggregation on something like max or min.  Additionally you can pivot dynamically, not knowing how many columns will be required.  Both problems have been asked and answered on SO and Database Admininstrator SE sites

Comment: @Prdp Assume that the result will alwys be 4 columns

Comment: I have been looking at this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026236/sql-server-columns-to-rows but I wasn't able to make it work for me

Comment: How about the values inside it will be always `1,2,3 & 4` or it can be anything

Comment: Yes those will always be `1, 2, 3 & 4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Row_Number` and `Pivot/Conditional Aggregation`

If the values in `col1` is always know then

```
;WITH cte
        AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY [col1] ORDER BY [col2]) rn, *
            FROM   Yourtable)
SELECT  [1] = Max(CASE WHEN [col1] = 1 THEN [col2] END),
        [2] = Max(CASE WHEN [col1] = 2 THEN [col2] END),
        [3] = Max(CASE WHEN [col1] = 3 THEN [col2] END),
        [4] = Max(CASE WHEN [col1] = 4 THEN [col2] END)
FROM   cte
GROUP  BY rn
```

Here is a dynamic approach

```
DECLARE @col_list VARCHAR(8000)= '',
        @sql      VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @col_list = (SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Quotename([col1])
                    FROM   Yourtable
                    FOR xml path (''))

SET @col_list = Stuff(@col_list, 1, 1, '')
SET @sql = 'select ' + @col_list
           + ' from (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY [col1] ORDER BY [col2]) rn, *
                FROM   Yourtable) a pivot (max([col2]) for col1 in ('
           + @col_list + '))pv'

PRINT @sql

EXEC (@sql)
```