# Sql server table has has month name as column, how to convert into multiple rows datewise

Tags: sql-server

Sql server DB has a table like

Input data:

```
Indicator name  Jan-17  Feb-17  Mar-17
A               5       2       9
B               0       5       3
C               9       6       3
D               9       1       8
```

I want to see the output as follows, how do I do that in sql server?

```
Indicator Name  Date    Value
A               Jan-17  5
A               Feb-17  2
A               Mar-17  9
B               Jan-17  0
B               Feb-17  5
B               Mar-17  3
C               Jan-17  9
C               Feb-17  6
C               Mar-17  3
D               Jan-17  9
D               Feb-17  1
D               Mar-17  8
```

Comment: You can use `UNPIVOT` operator. There are plenty of examples here in SO that demonstrate how you can unpivot a table.

Comment: Thanks it helps, but name of the columns keep on changing. e.g. if the data uploaded is for the month of June-2017 (Upload date) then it will have data from June-2016 until June-2017, similarly when it is uploaded lets say Aug-2017 then it will be from Aug-2016 until Aug-2017, is there any way to dynamically replace the "Jun-2016"and ""July-2016" in the query below,   select u.INDICATOR_GROUP_NAME, u.date, u.value
from xyz  s
unpivot
(
  value
  for date in ("Jun-2016", "Jul-2016")
) u;

Comment: in that case you have to use *dynamic sql*. There are also plenty of relevant examples here in SO. Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026236/sql-server-columns-to-rows) to one of these.