# use Column name in Query

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a table like this

```
Saleperson  Product1     Product2    saleDate
---------------------------------------------
A             500           300     120217
B             600           200     110217
```

what i want to do is

```
saleperson    newcolumn   saledate     Sale
--------------------------------------------
A             product1    120217       500
A             product2    120217       300
B             product1    110217       600
B             product2    110217       200
```

i tried to used pivot table but it seem to be not correct result. i get stuck in using Column name "product1, product2"

```
CREATE TABLE Sale(
saleperson VARCHAR(02) NOT NULL,
product1 int NOT NULL,
product2 int NOT NULL,
saleDate VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO sale(saleperson,product1,product1,saledate) 
VALUES 
 ("A",500,300,"120217"),
 ("B",600,200,"110217")
```

Comment: It's a great idea to do this and fix the bad table design. The new table is much closer to a good design. You should have a product table, though, and reference the product only by it's ID or product number in the sales table. Same for the sales person. Moreover: Why is your saledate a VARCHAR? And you are even storing a two digit year and use a non-sortable format! Change this to DATE. Then use VARCHAR2, not VARCHAR, in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unpivot()`.

```
SELECT *
FROM sale 
unpivot (Sale FOR product_code IN (product1, product2));
```

**Result:**

```
SALEPERSON  SALEDATE    PRODUCT_CODE    SALE
--------------------------------------------
A           120217      PRODUCT1        500
A           120217      PRODUCT2        300
B           110217      PRODUCT1        600
B           110217      PRODUCT2        200
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ebd84/12)**

Comment: thankyou zarruq. i need a dynamic solution because the productname changes monthly. that means this month there can be 2 products : product1,product2. but next month there may be some products more

Comment: @phalondon: This doesn't seem to make sense. Are you saying that next week there can suddenly be new columns in the table?

Answer (score 0):

Lets select details of `product1` and `product2` separately.

Then use `UNION ALL` to combine the results. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a912216/1)

```
select Saleperson, 'product1' as newColumn, saledate,  Product1 as sale
from saleperson 

union all

select Saleperson, 'product2' as newColumn, saledate,  Product2 as sale
from saleperson
```

Comment: That should be `UNION ALL`. There are no duplicates to remove, so don't use `UNION`. The delimiter for string literals is the single quote. Double quotes are for names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link, this may helps you. This Suggestion for MS SQL Server:

[SQL Server : Columns to Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026236/sql-server-columns-to-rows])

```
 select SALEPERSON,
  indicatorname PRODUCT_CODE,
  SALEDATE,
  indicatorvalue SALE
from Sale
unpivot
(
  indicatorvalue
  for indicatorname in (product1, product2)
) unpiv;
```

I just get the result from the above link.

```
SALEPERSON  PRODUCT_CODE    SALEDATE    SALE
A           product1        120217      500
A           product2        120217      300
B           product1        110217      600
B           product2        110217      200
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17861827)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Done.

Comment: Oracle is not SQL Server