# Getting different column values into one single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9XXg.png)I have 5 columns and i want to get values from those 5 columns and put them into a single column.

```
+---------------+----------+----------+----------+---------------+
| Option_1      | Option_2 | Option_3 | Option_4 | Option_5      |
+---------------+----------+----------+----------+---------------+
| Below average | Average  | Good     | Better   | Above average |
+---------------+----------+----------+----------+---------------+
```

So in output i want Below Average, Average, Good, Better and above Average in one column Named **Option**

Comment: which sql database?

Comment: concatenation differs in every RDBMS.

Comment: Hint:  `CONCAT()` or `||` or `+` or `&`.

Comment: Microsoft sql server @maSTAShuFu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server : Columns to Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026236/sql-server-columns-to-rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Union all** can be done:

```
SELECT
  Option1 AS Options
FROM (SELECT
  option1
FROM tablename
UNION ALL
SELECT
  option2
FROM tablename
UNION ALL
SELECT
  option3
FROM tablename
UNION ALL
SELECT
  option4
FROM tablename
UNION ALL
SELECT
  option5
FROM tablename) tablename;
```

or

`UNPIVOT` performs almost the reverse operation of `PIVOT`, by rotating columns into rows.

```
SELECT
  opt.Options
FROM (SELECT
  *
FROM yourtable) t
UNPIVOT (Options FOR tables IN ([Option_1], [Option_2], [Option_3], [Option_4], [Option_5])) AS opt
ORDER BY tables;
```

[image: output]

For more info please visit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot

Comment: I think i failed to make you understand my problem @Prabhath. I want Below average, Average, Good, Better, Above average in one column and in different rows.

Comment: I want output like.
**Option**
Below Average(next line)
Average(next line)
Good(next line)
Better(next line)
Above Average(next line)
I dont know how to make them into next line in comments

Comment: @Laxmi I'm unware about pivot and unpivot but as much as i searched on internet i got to know that one of these will work for me. I tried to implement but no success.

Comment: please refer the image i have linked for output. Thanks a lot for helping me but your query doesnt giving the desired output :/

Comment: :( @akshaysahu sorry...!! but i got the output

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(Option_1,', ',Option_2,', ',Option_3,' ,',Option_4,',',Option_5) as Option
FROM TAble1
```

if you want results as a one column but multiple rows

```
SELECT Option_1 AS Option     FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Option_2  AS Option  FROM  Table1
UNION ALL  
SELECT Option_3 AS Option  FROM Table1
UNION ALL  
SELECT Option_4 AS Option  FROM Table1
UNION ALL  
SELECT Option_5  AS Option  FROM Table1
```

Using `UNPIVOT`

```
SELECT
  rslt.Options
FROM (SELECT
  *
FROM Table1 ) AS dt
UNPIVOT (Options FOR tables IN ([Option_1], [Option_2], [Option_3], [Option_4], [Option_5])) AS rslt
```

Sample [Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e05a5/6)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @table table( Option_1 varchar(50),Option_2 varchar(50), Option_3 varchar(50), Option_4 varchar(50), Option_5  varchar(50))

insert into @table
select  'Below average', 'Average', 'Good','Better','Above average'

select p.typename,p.numericvalue from (
select * 
from @table
) a
unpivot(numericvalue for typename in([Option_1] ,[Option_2] , [Option_3] , [Option_4] , [Option_5]  )) as p
order by typename
```

output

```
typename    numericvalue
Option_1    Below average
Option_2    Average
Option_3    Good
Option_4    Better
Option_5    Above average
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample Data

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Sampletable')IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE Sampletable
GO
CREATE TABLE Sampletable (
      Option_1 varchar(50)
     ,Option_2 varchar(50)
     ,Option_3 varchar(50)
     ,Option_4 varchar(50)
     ,Option_5  varchar(50)
     )

INSERT INTO Sampletable
SELECT  'Below average', 'Average', 'Good','Better','Above average'
```

Using Dynamic Sql and Cross apply we get the expected result

```
DECLARE @DynamicCol nvarchar(max),@Sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @DynamicCol=
STUFF((SELECT ', '+'('+''''+COLUMN_NAME+''''+','+ COLUMN_NAME +')'FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='Sampletable'
FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')

SET @Sql='
SELECT   Typename
        ,Numericvalue 
FROM Sampletable t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES '+@DynamicCol+
    ') AS dt (Typename,Numericvalue )'
PRINT @Sql
EXEC (@Sql)
```

[Sample demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/235da/1)
Result

```
Typename    Numericvalue
-------------------------
Option_1    Below average
Option_2    Average
Option_3    Good
Option_4    Better
Option_5    Above average
```