# Create new record if column contains value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Wanted to know if I could "artificially" insert new records when a record contains a value for a specific column.  For example say I have this table in my database with the following two records:

```
Column1  Column2  Column3
-------------------------
DataA1   DataA2   null
DataB1   DataB2   DataB3
```

Now Column3 is the column I want to trigger an extra row if there is a value.  Column3 is essentially Column2 but with another value (this is non-normalized and I can't change it so I need to resort to a query instead). So I want to create a query that returns 3 rows using the example above and it should come out like this:

```
DataA1   DataA2
DataB1   DataB2
DataB1   DataB3
```

How do I write my sql to return the results above?

Comment: Just wanted to clarify that i want to insert the additional records in my sql select statement results, not in the actual table.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18026337/4892466

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use union all:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM TableName 
WHERE Column3 IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT Column1, Column3
FROM TableName 
WHERE Column3 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Actually my title is incorrect. I'm not trying to insert into a table but into the resultset returned by the sql query.  Hence I need to generate the additionaly records in my select sql.  sorry for confusion, english is not my native language.

Comment: hehe...you edited your answer just as I was posting mine. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not totally sure what you want here but I think you are looking for something like this.

```
select Column1
    , Column2
from SomeTable
where Column2 is not null

UNION ALL

select Column1
    , Column3
from SomeTable
where Column3 is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a UNION statement to merge a result set that uses the third column as the second column when the third column is not null:

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM Sample
UNION
SELECT column1, column3 
FROM Sample
WHERE column3 IS NOT NULL
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42ca15/6