# turn the distinct value of columns into a rows postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have a schema like:

```
 [ad_id] . [name] . [valueofname]
   1 .       name .   "brian"
   1 .       age  .    "23"
   2 .       job  .    "IT"
   2 .       name .    "Jack"
```

the row name contains multiple values : `age` , `name`, `birthday`, `job`, `age`
I'd like to convert it into this:

```
[ad_id] .   [name]  .      [age] .      [birthday] .    [job]
         [valueofname] [valueofname] [valueofname] [valueofname]
```

I have done the query for each line:

```
select * from where name='name'
select * from where name='age'
select * from where name='job'
```

I saw the example  [SQL Server : Columns to Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026236/sql-server-columns-to-rows). But it's the opposite of my problem.

Do you have any suggestion for making one scalable query in term of performance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns

Comment: @SandeshGupta thanks for  but how can i do just a select without creating a view ??

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: @GordonLinoff i am using both mysql and postgres from my app but the case here is in my postgres

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select ad_id,
       max(case when name = 'name' then valueofname end) as name,
       max(case when name = 'age' then valueofname end) as age,
       max(case when name = 'birthday' then valueofname end) as birthday,
       max(case when name = 'job' then valueofname end) as job
from t
group by ad_id;
```

In SQL Server, you can also do something similar with `pivot`.

Comment: Thanks but here the problem i have a string values so the max and sum will not work

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what about  if i have to do ae WHERE clauson the valueofname  to have just type of value needed

Comment: @Medone . . . You can cast the value to whatever type you think is appropriate.  The data in the database is being stored as a string.  However, for retrieving the value (assuming one per `ad_id`), the above is fine.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if there is no rows returned to replace it as a NULL instead of " " how it would be ? because some  names are missing from the database