# multiple condition on a row if not existed return a NULL postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I have a schema like:

```
[ad_id] .  [name] . [valueofname]
 1 .        name .    "brian"
 1 .        age  .    "23"
 2 .        job  .    "IT"
 2 .        name .    "Jack"
```

the row name contains multiple values : age , name, birthday, job, age I'd like to convert it into this:

```
[ad_id] .      [name]  .       [age] .              [birthday] .    [job]
[valueofad_id][valueofname] [valueofnameofage] [valueofnameofbirth] [valueofnameofjob]
```

I did this query selection below  to fix it , so in my program i must get the result where `ad_id`='xxxx' for each when `name`='`name` or `age` or `birthday` or `job` '

Some `ad_id` have not all the names , as you may see below the schema the `ad_id= 1` has just the `name` and `age` but not the `job` so i want when the job not found it returns a `NULL`

```
 [ad_id] .  [name] . [valueofname]
  1 .        name .    "brian"
  1 .        age  .    "23"
  2 .        job  .    "IT"
  2 .        name .    "Jack" 


select ad_id,

max(case when name = 'name' and ad_id='xxx' then valueofname end) as name,
max(case when name = 'age' and ad_id='xxx'  then valueofname end) as age,
max(case when name = 'birthday' and ad_id='xxx' then valueofname end) as birthday,
max(case when name = 'job' and ad_id='xxx' then valueofname end) as job

from t
group by ad_id;
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? (Don't add tags for products not involved.)

Comment: @jarlh i am using Postgresql , the purpose for is that it can be a model for both

Comment: What is the data type of `valueofname` ? Please add table schema.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Remove the `and ad_id='xxx' ` parts from the case expressions. (Handled by GROUP BY.)

Comment: You can use [`NULLIF`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF) if you want `NULL` instead of `""`.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen for the collaboration what you know is just bad voting instead of helping

Comment: @mkopriva  [The start of my problem ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49793575/turn-the-distinct-value-of-columns-into-a-rows-postgres/49853146#49853146). so now when i got the ad_id as condition if existed it returns the valueofname else return NULL for each name

Comment: mr @jarlh here is more details on my problem :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49793575/turn-the-distinct-value-of-columns-into-a-rows-postgres/49853146#49853146. thanks indeed

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name hope that is more clear , thanks indeed for your help

Comment: @jarlh i edited  hope that is more clear , sorry for any unclear things i still learning how to use the platform

Comment: @dev_medo Something like this? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8603ee/3 (updated link)

Comment: @mkopriva yeep that's  totally what i am looking for as a result i used your query  but i am getting just a blank instead of NULL  , i looked at the description of my table and i found that value is set as not NULL does make any sence ?? for not accepting to be NULL

Comment: @dev_medo how did you test the query? For example `psql` by defaut displays NULLs as blanks and so cannot be easily discerned from an empty string. If you do `SELECT NULL;` do you see NULL? or a blank? or something else? While in `psql` you can change how NULLs are displayed with this command `\pset null '(null)'`, this will display NULLs as the string *(null)*.

Comment: yeep i checked that and it was the case when i parse them into json  thanks indeed for @mkopriva

Comment: @ mkopriva could you please review this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859521/merge-two-queries-with-join-and-where-and-group-by-conditions-golang-postg/49860569#49860569

Answer (score 0):

To flatten the records for *all* `ad_id`s, use:

```
select ad_id,
       max(case when name = 'name' then valueofname end) as name,
       max(case when name = 'age'then valueofname end) as age,
       max(case when name = 'birthday' then valueofname end) as birthday,
       max(case when name = 'job' then valueofname end) as job
from t
group by ad_id;
```

To get the results for a single `ad_id`, add a `where` clause:

```
select ad_id,
       max(case when name = 'name' then valueofname end) as name,
       max(case when name = 'age'then valueofname end) as age,
       max(case when name = 'birthday' then valueofname end) as birthday,
       max(case when name = 'job' then valueofname end) as job
from t
where ad_id = 'xxx' 
group by ad_id;
```

Note:  If there are no rows with `ad_id = 'xxx'` then this will return no rows.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff It's working moreover the having clause is working also , but the `NULL` problem still existing  for the `value` field description: [Type:`Text` ; `NOT NULL`] but the selection made is just a temporary table so the `NOT NULL`is not applicated