# Transposing a SQL query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I  have a query that produces a table that looks like this:

```
+----------------+-----------+------------+----------+
| CustomerNumber | FirstName | MiddleName | LastName |
+----------------+-----------+------------+----------+
|         123456 | Test      | Test1      | Test2    |
+----------------+-----------+------------+----------+
```

What I am needing is for the table to look like this:

```
+----------------+--------+
| CustomerNumber | 123456 |
+----------------+--------+
| FirstName      | Test   |
| MiddleName     | Test1  |
| LastName       | Test2  |
+----------------+--------+
```

This is my current sql query:

```
SELECT 
        CustomerNumber,
        FirstName,
        MiddleName,
        LastName
FROM    Customers
WHERE   CustermerNumber = 123456
```

Is there a way to complete this? I have been looking at transposing it via unpivot but have not been able to understand how.

Comment: It seems like you are looking for dynamic unpivot, which would be the last example from [**Taryn's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026236/sql-server-columns-to-rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` :

```
select tt.*
from table t cross apply ( 
         values ('CustomerNumber', CustomerNumber), ('FirstName', FirstName),
                 ('MiddleName', MiddleName), ('LastName', LastName)
       ) tt (name, v);
```

Answer (score 1):

With dynamic TSQL pivoting you can also manage multiple rows input:

```
if OBJECT_ID('Test') is not null 
    drop table [dbo].[Test] 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](CustomerNumber varchar(10), FirstName varchar(10), 
                          MiddleName varchar(10), LastName varchar(10)) 

--populate test table
insert into [dbo].[Test] values
 (123456, 'Test','Test1','Test2')
 , (234567, 'Test_2','Test_21','Test_22')
 , (345678, 'Test_3','Test_31','Test_32')

--this variable holds all the customer numbers that will become column names 
declare @columns nvarchar(max)='' 
--this variable contains the dinamically generated TSQL code
declare @sql nvarchar(max)=''     

select @columns = @columns + ', [' + [CustomerNumber] + ']' from [dbo].[Test] 
set @columns = RIGHT(@columns, len(@columns)-2) 

set @sql = @sql + 'select piv.COL as CustomerNumber, ' + @columns 
set @sql = @sql + ' from ' 
set @sql = @sql + ' ( ' 
set @sql = @sql + '  select [CustomerNumber], col, val, ord ' 
set @sql = @sql + '  from [dbo].[Test] ' 
set @sql = @sql + '  CROSS APPLY (' 
set @sql = @sql + '  VALUES (''FirstName'' ,FirstName , 1), ' 
set @sql = @sql + '         (''MiddleName'',MiddleName, 2), ' 
set @sql = @sql + '         (''LastName''  ,LastName,   3) ' 
set @sql = @sql + '  )CS (COL,VAL,ORD) ' 
set @sql = @sql + ' ) src ' 
set @sql = @sql + ' pivot ( max(val) for [CustomerNumber] in ('+@columns+') ) piv' 
set @sql = @sql + ' order by ord' 

exec(@sql)
```

Sample input and output with **one row**:

[image]

Sample input and output with **three rows**:

[image]