# Smarter code to query the same parameter from multiple columns?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have this very wide table that has 25 diagnosis code columns:

```
diag1, diag2, … diag25.
```

If I want to look for diagnosis code '12345' I need to write

```
diag1 ='12345' or diag2='12345' or diag3='12345'... or diag25='12345'
```

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
diag1-diag25 ='12345'
```

Comment: Are you able to redesign your data table?  These diagnosis codes should each be within their own row.

Comment: not right now, maybe in the future after ok from multiple decision makers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might call the generic abilities of XML to your rescue. Not very fast with may rows, but very mighty:

(credits to iamdave for the mockup)

```
declare @t table(id int,diag1 int,diag2 int,diag3 int,diag4 int,diag5 int,diag6 int,diag7 int,diag8 int,diag9 int,diag10 int);
insert into @t (id, diag5) values(1,12345);
insert into @t (id, diag3) values(2,123);
insert into @t (id, diag8, diag1) values(3,123,12345);
insert into @t (id, diag9, diag2) values(4,345,678);

WITH CreateXML AS
(
    SELECT * 
          ,(
            SELECT *
            FROM @t t2
            WHERE t1.id=t2.id
            FOR XML PATH('codes'),TYPE
           ).query('/codes/*[substring(local-name(),1,4)="diag"]') AllCodes
     FROM @t t1 
)
SELECT * 
FROM CreateXML
WHERE AllCodes.exist('/*[. cast as xs:int? >=12345 and . cast as xs:int? <=12349]')=1;
```

The query will use a `SELECT *` to create an XML of all columns. The `.query()` will pick all elements starting with `"diag"`. Maybe you have to adapt this to your needs.

The `.exist()` will check, if any value within these elements is between your borders. One match is enough.

Good Luck!

Comment: I thought the XML tricks was John Cappelletti's department ;-) This is a good option for searching a range of values. +1.

Comment: Upvotes to the answer and the comment, because as soon as I started reading, I assumed it was John.

Comment: @ZoharPeled yeah  if there are exactly 25 columns an unpivoting with value would be better. But in cases where you must deal with unknown sets xml is very mighty...

Comment: @EricBrandt funny ask him, where he learnt that xml stuff 

Answer (score 4):

You can write

```
'12345' IN (diag1, diag2, ..., diag25)
```

but there is no syntax for diag1-diag25

Comment: WOW did not know this was possible.  

What about if the parameter was '12345' between '12349' ?

Comment: also -- what is this style of querying called? I tried googling WHERE condition in (column list) and no dice

Comment: I don't think the style has any particular name - this is just "IN" syntax https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @LeeY.  Your question of *if the parameter was '12345' between '12349'?* is where this approach has limitations.  You can do this with a more flexible unpivot approach though.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin , is there a function to return the first column that meets the condition?  For example,  '12345' in (diag1,diag2,diag3) ; which column has '12345' ?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative and potentially more flexible solution is to unpivot the data using `cross apply`:

```
declare @t table(id int,diag1 int,diag2 int,diag3 int,diag4 int,diag5 int,diag6 int,diag7 int,diag8 int,diag9 int,diag10 int);
insert into @t (id, diag5) values(1,12345);
insert into @t (id, diag3) values(2,123);
insert into @t (id, diag8, diag1) values(3,123,12345);
insert into @t (id, diag9, diag2) values(4,345,678);

select t.id
      ,d.d
from @t as t
    cross apply(values(diag1),(diag2),(diag3),(diag4),(diag5),(diag6),(diag7),(diag8),(diag9),(diag10)) d(d)
where d.d = 12345;
```

Output:

```
+----+-------+
| id |   d   |
+----+-------+
|  1 | 12345 |
|  3 | 12345 |
+----+-------+
```

Comment: Upvote from my side. Probably the best way to deal with a known set of column names. And thx for you mockup. I borrowed it for my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually all these `diagxx` columns should be in a seperate table. So your design should be altered.

If you cannot do that then you can make your query easier en cleaner by using an  `IN` in your where clause.

```
declare @d table (diag1 varchar(5), diag2 varchar(5), diag3 varchar(5))
insert into @d values ('12345', '23456', '34567'),
                      ('45678', '12345', '56789'),
                      ('45678', '85236', '56789')
select * 
from   @d
where  '12345' in (diag1, diag2, diag3)
```

This will return

```
diag1   diag2   diag3   
-----   -----   -----   
12345   23456   34567   
45678   12345   56789
```

This is as close to your desired syntax as you are going to get

Comment: I agree.  Unfortunately office politics

Comment: Well the `where IN ()` workaround will make your work somewhat easier then

Comment: that might be what I have to do.  Though I could not get a between statement in work with the where in ()

Comment: What do you mean with a between statement ? Can you explain what you want to do

Comment: something like this:  WHERE '12345' between '12349' in (diag1,diag2,diag3)  , the real business scenario is about 70 diagnosis codes captured between C00 and C96

Comment: OK I understand. I am not sure if there is a way to do that I will think about it. I am afraid you will need to do `where '12345' in (diag1,..., diag25) or '12346' in (diag1,..., diag25)` and so on

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to `UNPIVOT` your diagnosis codes into a single column, then query the resulting data set.

For a full discussion of unpivoting options, see this question. [SQL Server : Columns to Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026236/sql-server-columns-to-rows)

With `varchar` diagnosis codes, `BETWEEN` might not behave the way you want it to, but you could dump your 70-odd codes into a temp table and join to it.

But something along these lines:

```
select * from 
(
  select 
    <Any Key Fields You Want To Include>,
    diagColumnName,
    diagCode
  from yourtable
  unpivot
  (
    diagCode
    for diagColumnName in (diag1, diag2....diag25)
  ) as unpiv
) as resultSet
join #tempCodes as t
  on t.diagCode = resultSet.diagCode
```

**Edit**: added the join/temp table based on comments.

Comment: Edited my answer to account for searching a pile of diagnosis codes.