# query to convert column to row in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, pivot, unpivot

need to convert this column to row

```
select okeydata
 from [elo].[dbo].[objkeys] 
 where parentid 
 in 
  ( select parentid from
   [elo].[dbo].[objekte] inner join [elo].[dbo].[objkeys] 
   on objid = parentid and objmask like 26 and okeydata like 1 )
```

acutal output

```
okeydata  
1
a
a@a.com
london
```

need query to be

```
okeydata  
1  a a@a.com london
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What determines the order of those rows/columns? There are plenty of examples on  how to pivot data on Stack Overflow; what was wrong with those examples?

Comment: If you are on SQL Server 2017, look into `STRING_AGG`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server : Columns to Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026236/sql-server-columns-to-rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want four columns, you can use `row_number()` or `pivot`:

```
select max(case when seqnum = 1 then okeydata end) as col_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then okeydata end) as col_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then okeydata end) as col_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then okeydata end) as col_4
from (select okeydata,
             row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from [elo].[dbo].[objkeys] 
      where parentid in (select parentid
                         from [elo].[dbo].[objekte] inner join
                              [elo].[dbo].[objkeys] 
                               on objid = parentid 
                         where objmask like 26 and okeydata like 1 
                        )
     ) o;
```