# How can I transpose a query result in SQL?

Tags: sql, transpose, unpivot

As the result of many subqueries, I have the following table:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| register | simulation | hasLimit | approved |
+---------------------------------------------+
|     X    |     Y      |    Z     |    W     |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
+----------------+
| register   | X | 
+----------------+
| simulation | Y | 
+----------------+
| hasLimit   | Z | 
+----------------+
| approved   | W | 
+----------------+
```

In R I would simply transpose using the function t(), however in SQL it seems a bit harder. I've tried to understand the function pivot to apply in this case, but it seems a little strange, since I'm actually just transposing, not pivoting anything.

Comment: Tag your question with the DBMS you are using (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL etc.)

Comment: "Columns to Rows SQL" in Google should do it.

Comment: Has already been answered here before:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026236/sql-server-columns-to-rows

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want an "unpivot" operation.

Assuming the types of the columns are all compatible, you can use `union all`:

```
select 'register' as which, register as value union all
select 'simulation',  simulation union all
select 'hasLimit', hasLimit union all
select 'approved', approved;
```

Some databases require a `FROM` clause for each subquery, such as `from dual`.

This is a very small amount of data.  For larger data, I prefer a lateral join, but the syntax (and availability of which) depends on the database.

Comment: The table that I present in the beginning is not a table itself, is the result of a lot of queries side by side, that I put all together in a single query, and each individual query gives me a certain number (X, Y, Z, W). I think I have to use the unpivot function, but I couldn't find how to do that INSIDE the query that generates this result

Comment: @EduardaOliveira to be able to use unpivoting we need to make sure your DBMS product is suitable for it. i.e. you need to tell your DBMS firsty.

Answer (score 0):

Given the return from

```
         SELECT 'x' AS register
              , 'y' AS simulation
              , 'z' AS hasLimit
              , 'w' AS approved
```

We can wrap that in a set of parens and reference it as an inline view in an outer query.

For example:

```
SELECT CASE i.n
         WHEN 1 THEN 'register'
         WHEN 2 THEN 'simulation'
         WHEN 3 THEN 'hasLimit'
         WHEN 4 THEN 'approved'
       END AS col1
     , CASE i.n
         WHEN 1 THEN q.register
         WHEN 2 THEN q.simulation
         WHEN 3 THEN q.hasLimit
         WHEN 4 THEN q.approved
       END AS col2
  FROM (
         SELECT 'x' AS register
              , 'y' AS simulation
              , 'z' AS hasLimit
              , 'w' AS approved
       ) q
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT 1 AS n
         UNION ALL SELECT 2
         UNION ALL SELECT 3
         UNION ALL SELECT 4
       ) i
 ORDER
    BY i.n
```

---

That seems a bit of a rigmarole, given that you already have subqueries that are returning scalar values, we could combine those with `UNION ALL` set operators

```
SELECT 'register'  AS col1, ( scalar_subquery_for_x ) AS col2
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'simulation'       , ( scalar_subquery_for_y )
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'hasLimit'         , ( scalar_subquery_for_z )
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'approved'         , ( scalar_subquery_for_w )
```

IF we need a guaranteed order, we can wrap that whole thing in parens and add an ORDER BY clause. (Without the ORDER BY, we do observe rows are returned "in order" from the `UNION ALL`, but this behavior is not guaranteed.)

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple `UNPIVOT` as below,

```
SELECT Col, Val
FROM <Your Table>
UNPIVOT (Val FOR Col IN([register],[simulation],[hasLimit],[approved])) unpiv
```