# Convert Column Data into Row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have following Store Procedure.

```sql
Declare @myData TABLE( 
                        Id int,
                        Note1 nvarchar(Max),
                        Note2 nvarchar(Max),
                        Note3 nvarchar(Max),
                    )
Insert into @myData (Id,Note1,Note2,Note3)
Select
--First Column
E.Id as [ID],
E.Notes as [Note1],
E.NotesDate as [Date1]

F.ItemDescription as [Note2],
F.DescriptionDate as [Date2]

G.Description as [Note3],
G.DescDate as [Date3]

From 
Employee E
LEFT Join Tab1 as F
    on I.EmpId = E.Id
LEFT join Tab2 AS G 
    on G.EmpId = E.Id
where E.Id = 1019
select * from @myData
```

It gives Following result table.

```
+------+----------+------------+-------+-------------+---------+--------------+
| ID   | Note1    | Date1      | Note2 |  Date2      |  Note3   | Date3       |
+------+----------+------------+-------+-------------+----------+-------------+
|    1 | admils   | 2020-07-02 |  sadd |  2020-06-08 |  1230    | 2020-05-06  |
+------+----------+--------+---------+---------------+----------+-------------+
```

Now i need resulting table some thing like below...

```
+------+----------+-------------+--------+
| ID   | Note1    | Date        | Col    |
+------+----------+-------------+--------+
|    1 | admils   | 2020-07-02  |    1   | <- Because This Data is from Note1 Column
|    1 | sadd     | 2020-06-08  |    2   | <- Because This Data is from Note2 Column
|    1 | 1230     | 2020-05-06  |    3   | <- Because This Data is from Note3 Column
+------+----------+-------------+--------+
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server : Columns to Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18026236/2029983)

Comment: @Larnu yes this is helpful but showing redundant data because of left join.

Comment: Then change to an `INNER JOIN`? What do you mean by "redundant"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just unpivot your data, as shown in the linked [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18026236/2029983) candidate. I prefer using `VALUES` over `UNPIVOT` as it's less restrictive:

```sql
SELECT E.ID,
       V.[Description],
       V.[Date],
       V.Col
FROM dbo.Employee E
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Tab1 T1 ON E.ID = T1.EmpID
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Tab2 T2 ON E.ID = T2.EmpID
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1,E.NotesDate,E.Notes),
                        (2,T1.DescriptionDate,T1.ItemDescription),
                        (3,T2.DescDate,T2.Description))V(Col,[Date],[Description]);
```

Comment: This Works good but I am getting Same Record multiple times, can you help me with this. (I meant this by "Redundant" data)

Comment: Not without sample data, @MaulikDave .

Comment: [Here's](https://www.screencast.com/t/GsvEcQXPChvt) the Sample Data, I think I can use `DISTINCT` But can not figure out where.

Comment: I don't know what that link is, but I'm not clicking it, @MaulikDave . You're better off asking a new question with realistic sample data at this stage, as there are no duplicates in your one example.

Comment: That Link is of The Snap shot of The sample Data but it's Okay.. I Will ask new question.

Comment: As I thought I used `DISTINCT *` and it Worked