# columns to rows moving headers

Tags: pivot, transpose

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEJ9O.png)

The table uses the row description (Date) and Header to categorize the values.  This is what my output must look like.

Comment: Hi, you maybe should specify which sql dialect are you using.

Comment: For example take SQL Server look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026236/sql-server-columns-to-rows