# Unpivot columns to rows

Tags: sql-server, unpivot, sql-server-2019

I read this [SQL Server : Columns to Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026236/sql-server-columns-to-rows).
How can I make sure that the order in which the rows appear in the result will be the same as the order of the columns?

Comment: With an `ORDER BY` that defines that order. The *only* way you can guarantee the order of data in a result set is with a deterministic `ORDER BY`.

Comment: I asked the order of the columns not the order of the columns name. This will only work if these two match

Comment: My answer below demonstrates that to not be true.

Comment: You should add some data and expected results so it's possible to give you more concrete answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, with an `ORDER BY`. If you're using the `UNPIVOT` operator, you may find this difficult if the names of the columns alphabetically don't match the ordinal positions. For example, if you have the following columns in the following order `Surname`, `FirstName`, `PreferredColour`, then ordering the columns by name would get you `FirstName`, `PreferredColour`, `Surname`.

As `UNPIVOT` is pretty restrictive (like `PIVOT`), you can instead use a`VALUES` table construct. This makes it much easier, as you can add a column to the construct to `ORDER BY`:

```sql
SELECT YT.KeyColumn,
       UP.ColumnName,
       UP.ColumnValue
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(1,N'Surname',YT.Surname),
                       (2,N'FirstName',YT.FirstName),
                       (3,N'PerferredColour',YT.PreferredColour))UP(Ordinal,ColumnName,ColumnValue)
ORDER BY YT.KeyColumn,
         UP.Ordinal;
```

Comment: I see now. If additionally we want an extra column with sort order id per group based on  KeyColumn?

Comment: I'm  not sure what you're asking there, but the `ORDER BY` can be what ever you need.

Comment: I mean a column that increased based on column order. surname1--->1,surname2--->2 etc and this pattern resets every time the KeyColumn changed.

Comment: I still don't follow what this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77352529/unpivot-columns-to-rows/77352635?noredirect=1#comment136367582_77352635) means. *"Also this approach fetch the NULL value"* Then just add `WHERE ColumnValue IS NOT NULL`. You've given  no information on your data in the question. If you want a complete answer to your scenario, then provide a complete question with details of your scenario. I would suggest that you likely have a follow up question, and so should be posting a [New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for your specific scenario.

Comment: It is ok. I made a typo. Just I meant that UNPIVOT excludes the NULL