# Display one record field values into row by row

Tags: sql

How to display one record values in row by row in SQL . Please help on that

Ex:

```
EMPID EMPNAME EMPADDRESS  EMPCOUNTRY
1     TEST    HYD         INDIA
```

Need to Display as like below

```
ID   VALUE
10   TEST
10   HYD
10   INDIA
```

Please note, 10 is a another unique field value that is single field

Comment: What DBMS are you using? This is called an UNPIVOT. Example for sql server here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026236/sql-server-columns-to-rows . I don't know what this means "10 is a another unique field value that is single field". I assume the "1" id in the first sample of data was supposed to be 10? If you only have 3 columns you can use a sequence of UNIONS, more than a few look in to the UNPIVOT syntax supported by your DBMS.

Comment: Tables have _rows_ and _columns_. (Records and fields are something else in SQL.)

Comment: Where do you find the `10`. A [mcve] is supposed to be _consistent_.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you use `SQL SERVER`. Here is the sample code:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
    EMPID INT,
    EMPNAME VARCHAR(50),
    EMPADDRESS VARCHAR(50),
    EMPCOUNTRY VARCHAR(50)
);


INSERT INTO Employee (EMPID, EMPNAME, EMPADDRESS, EMPCOUNTRY)
VALUES (1, 'TEST', 'HYD', 'INDIA');

--10 comes from another table
SELECT 10 AS ID, EMPNAME AS VALUE FROM Employee WHERE EMPID = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 10 AS ID, EMPADDRESS AS VALUE FROM Employee WHERE EMPID = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 10 AS ID, EMPCOUNTRY AS VALUE FROM Employee WHERE EMPID = 1;
```

OR you can use `UNPIVOT`

```
SELECT 
    10 AS ID, 
    COLUMN_VALUE AS VALUE
FROM (
    SELECT EMPNAME, EMPADDRESS, EMPCOUNTRY
    FROM Employee
    WHERE EMPID = 1
) t
UNPIVOT (
    COLUMN_VALUE FOR COLUMN_NAME IN (EMPNAME, EMPADDRESS, EMPCOUNTRY)
) unpvt;
```

Here is the output :

[image]

You can check [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yZd_F8YF) for implementation