# Convert single rows to multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an output which looks like

| Title A | Title B | Title C | Title D | Title E | Title F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 | Value 4 | Value 5 | Value 6 |

I need the output to be in this format:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Title A | Value 1 |
| Title B | Value 2 |
| Title C | Value 3 |
| Title D | Value 4 |
| Title E | Value 5 |
| Title F | Value 6 |

Comment: You should rather show us the original data and query used to generate this output.

Comment: SELECT  
sum(case when condition = 'A' then [Total] else 0 end ) as [A]
,sum(case when condition = 'B' then [Total ] else 0 end ) as [B]
,sum(case when condition = 'C' then [Total ] else 0 end ) as [C]
,sum(case when condition = 'D' then [Total] else 0 end ) as [D]
from table 

and the output is as in the question

Comment: You are probably looking for `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT`. Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16) MS doc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server : Columns to Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026236/sql-server-columns-to-rows)  The top answer shows the two most common ways to do this - `UNPIVOT` and `CROSS APPLY(...VALUES...)`.

Answer (score -1):

I reckon you should change your original query to something along these lines:

```sql
SELECT condition AS ColumnA, COALESCE(SUM(Total), 0) AS ColumnB
FROM yourTable
WHERE condition IN ('A', 'B', ...)
GROUP BY condition;
```

Answer (score -2):

Below Query will help you:

```
Drop table if exists #TempYourTable
CREATE table #TempYourTable (COLUMN_NAME nvarchar(500), COLUMN_VALUE nvarchar(max))

insert into #TempYourTable (COLUMN_NAME) 
select COLUMN_NAME 
from
(
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'yourTable'
) as tbl_col_nm


Declare @Query nvarchar(max);
SELECT 
    @Query = ISNULL(@Query +';', '') + ISNULL('update #TempYourTable set COLUMN_VALUE = (select top 1 '+ isnull(T.COLUMN_NAME,'')+' from yourTable) where COLUMN_NAME = '''+T.COLUMN_NAME+'''', '')
FROM 
( 
    select COLUMN_NAME as COLUMN_NAME    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'yourTable'
)T

print @Query
Exec(@Query) 

select * from #TempYourTable
```

Comment: It appears that this is attempting to perform a PIVOT operation, instead of the UNPIVOT as requested by the OP.  (It is also doing so in a most inefficient way using an unnecessary temp table, and with logic that is not scalable to multiple input rows.)

Answer (score -2):

This is just a simple unpivot:

```sql
select col, value
from (
    VALUES  (N'Value 1', N'Value 2', N'Value 3', N'Value 4', N'Value 5', N'Value 6')
) t ([Title A],[Title B],[Title C],[Title D],[Title E],[Title F])
unpivot (value for col in ([Title A],[Title B],[Title C],[Title D],[Title E],[Title F])) upv
```

If you want dynamic one, there are plenty of answers available