# Most efficient way to periodically copy an entire SQL database table to another [history] table

Tags: sql

I want to periodically copy the entire contents of a table to a second history table, which is identical, except for an extra datetime column. The 'live' table can have up to 100,000 rows, which need copying over every hour, or maybe less.

```
using (var db = new MyProjectEntities())
{
    var newData = from d in db.Data select d;
    foreach (var d in newData)
    {
        var histData = new DataHistory
        {
            DataName = d.DataName,
            DataType = d.DataType,
            DataValue = d.DataValue,
            Id = d.Id,
            SnapshotDate = DateTime.Now
        };
        db.DataHistories.Add(histData);
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Is this really the best and most efficient way to do this? The history table is for data mining and producing graphs of data changes over time ranges, etc.

Comment: What DBMS you are using?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, functionally?  Copying a whole table on a regular basis appears unusual.

Answer (score 2):

You have not said which RDBMS but I have based this on MS SQL Server

Just run a SQL command a bit like:

```
INSERT INTO SnapShotTable (DataName, DataType, DataValue, Id, SnapshotDate)
SELECT DataName, DataType, DataValue, Id, GetDate()
FROM SourceTable
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think using something like a script called with a specific job fired by SQL Agent would probably be relatively efficient.

Heading into managed code, using LINQ and EF would certainly NOT be efficient, but might be simple

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use triggers for auditing, this way every database operation gets audited without the need to schedule periodic jobs.

I'll refrain from going into detail and instead refer to an earlier post on the subject:

[Creating audit triggers in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962398/creating-audit-triggers-in-sql-server)