# SSRS Audit Report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, audit

I'm trying to create and Audit report for different tables.

I'd like to use an generic table structure for the report which will be temp.

I was thinking something like this:

```
AuditID
,TableName
,FieldName
,OldValue
,NewValue
,DateAction
,UserName
,ActionType (update, insert, delete)
```

I've already created the `audit` table with same structure plus all field duplicated and action type. (this was a request)

Now I need to group it for the report.
following an example of `audit table` I've created

```
tblTest_audit
(
ID
ID_new
Name
Name_new
Address
Address_new
)
```

How can I fill my `temp table`? Any suggestions are really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962398/creating-audit-triggers-in-sql-server

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21068/Audit-Trail-Generator-for-Microsoft-SQL